# Why do is the content of a buffer deleted, when it reads an empty rdbuf?

Tags: c++, stream, streambuf

Quick example [(play with code)](https://godbolt.org/z/cju4ub):

```
int main() 
{
   
    std::stringstream sstr;
    sstr << "hello\n";
    sstr << "world\n";

    std::stringstream sstr2;
    // sstr2 << "test\n";
    if (sstr2.rdbuf()->in_avail() != 0)
    {    
        sstr << sstr2.rdbuf();
    }

    print_me(sstr);

    return 0;
}
```

I have a stream `sstr`. That stream holds data. I also want it to hold all other data that is stored in `sstr2`. For that I use `sstr << sstr2.rdbuf();`. If I execute that line when `sstr2` is empty, then `sstr` will also be empty. Why is that?

PS: I know that I can protect myself from this scenario by using `if (sstr2.rdbuf()->in_avail() != 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the old value you should use code like this :

```
sstr <<  sstr.rdbuf() << sstr2.rdbuf();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. But why does the code result in an error?